# Quantification and qualification of total solar electromagnetic output from Earth's perspective

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, sun

I've tried tracking down the specifics, but [this article](https://www.businessinsider.com/this-is-the-potential-of-solar-power-2015-9) mentions that the total energy output that Earth receives from Sol annually is ~430E18 J.  The article links back to the US Department of Energy Office of Science, but not to any particular paper or article.  Aside from this, I've had difficulty finding estimation of solar output from Earth, especially with specifics as to how inclusive those values are (are they infrared/visible/UV light ranges? Do they include x-ray and gamma waves?).

Ultimately, I'm trying to track down a current best estimate of the total energy of all electromagnetic waves generated by Sol from the perspective Solar-facing Earth at any given moment.

Comment: *total energy ... at any given moment* Do you mean total *power*?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant

Comment: Are you asking about the solar "constant" at 1 AU of ~1380 W $m^{-2}$?